# spring integration idempotent metadatastore message going to same store

Tags: spring-integration

I am using s3 module to poll files from s3.It downloads the file to local system and starts processing it.I am running this on 3 node cluster with module count as 1.Now lets assume the file is downloaded to local system from s3 and xd is processing it.If xd node goes down it would have processed half the message.When the server comes up it will start processing file again hence I will get duplicate message.I am trying to change to idempotent pattern with message store to change the module count to 3 but still this duplicate message issues will be there.

This configuration worked for me thanks for the help

```
 <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true">
        <int:advice-chain>
            <ref bean="pollAdvise"/>

        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>


    <bean id="pollAdvise" class="org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice">
        <constructor-arg ref="healthCheckStrategy"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="healthCheckStrategy" class="test.ServiceHealthCheckPollSkipStrategy">
        <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="doHealthCheck" value="${doHealthCheck}"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
        <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
        <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
        <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
        <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
    <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                        bucket="${bucket}"
                                        s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                        credentials-ref="credentials"
                                        file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                        remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                        channel="splitChannel"
                                        local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                        accept-sub-folders="false"
                                        delete-source-files="true"
                                        archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                        archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-file:splitter id="s3splitter" input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="bridge" markers="false" charset="UTF-8">

        <int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
            </bean>
        </int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>

    </int-file:splitter>
```

I had few doubts wanted to clarify If i am doing right.

1)As you can see I have ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice to delete the file.Will the file get deleted after i read the file into redis or after last record is read?

2)I explored redis using desktop manager I see this I have a MetaData [image]

Both (file and payload) metadatastore key and value are going to same table is this fine?or should it be different metadatastore?

Can i use hash of payload instead of payload as key?Is there something like payload.hash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you still don't show enough config to determine the issue.

There is neither `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, nor `s3splitter` and even S3 Inbound Channel adapter.

Anyway I'll try to answer to your questions.

I'd say that the best place to use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with the file delete is your `FileSplitter`. And it is deleted after the last record is read. Actually the store into the Redis via the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` is done even before any splitting logic is involved. That is a premise of the Idempotent Receiver: do not pass the message to the target endpoint, if we don't accept the duplicate messages:

```
boolean accept = this.messageSelector.accept(message);
    if (!accept) {
        boolean discarded = false;
 .....
```

Yes, looks like you should use different `RedisMetadataStore` instances with different keys. But that may be the same Redis Server.

Not sure what you mean about `payload.hash`. Any Java Object has its own `hashCode()`. Although I'm sure you have there after splitting the strings representing each line from the file. So, I think you really should use there something like MD5:

```
new BigInteger(1, md5.digest(value.toUpperCase().getBytes('UTF-8'))).toString(16).toUpperCase()
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. For me that doesn't matter (yet), but for other guys. Please, add the rest config as well :-). And let me know what you think about my answer!